# Get NSData for video file with NSUrl

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdata, phasset

I have file at path

```
var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0292.MOV
```

and I want to get NSData of this file but I got error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_0292.MOV”
>   couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0292.MOV,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x178c9f90 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}

I tried with

```
NSError *error;
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&error];
```

and

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

and no luck.

I also have PHAsset of video file but don't know how to get NSData from it. 
Please help me get NSData.

Comment: Have you asked for permissions for access to photo library?

Comment: Yes I do. permission granted

Comment: @Ossir make options as nil and try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access URLs directly that are not within your apps sandbox (without a few exceptions).
To get the data for a video file, please take a look at the following methods:

For iOS 9 or higher use the following method of PHAssetResource:

```
- (PHAssetResourceDataRequestID)requestDataForAssetResource:(PHAssetResource *)resource options:(PHAssetResourceRequestOptions *)options dataReceivedHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data))handlercompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

For iOS 8 or higher:

```
- (PHImageRequestID)requestExportSessionForVideo:(PHAsset *)asset options:(PHVideoRequestOptions *)options exportPreset:(NSString *)exportPreset resultHandler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler;
```

Then read the NSData of the exported URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion sake.. This worked for me:

```
    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    [manager requestAVAssetForVideo:asset.baseAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {

        if([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]){
             //Get the url 
             NSURL *url = [(AVURLAsset *)asset URL];
        }

    }];
```

Hope this helps.